# Complete partially filled in columns, based on established relationships between columns

Tags: r

I'm looking to complete a two columns which are based on each other, however they are partially filled.

```
 title <- c("Mrs", "Ms", "", "Ms", "Mr", "Mr", "")
 gender <- c("female", "", "male", "female", "", "Male", "female")

 df <- as.data.frame(cbind(title, gender))

 df 

    title gender
 1   Mrs female
 2    Ms       
 3         male
 4    Ms female
 5    Mr       
 6    Mr   Male
```

In this example, we know that if `title=Mrs` or `Ms`, then gender should be filled in with `female`, and if `title=Mr` then gender should be filled in as `male`. On the flip side if only gender is filled in to be `female`, then title should be `Ms`, or for `male` title should be `Mr`.

To add to this, how would you be able to complete a partially filled table without having to establish the relationships beforehand. Refer to the example below:

```
c1 <- paste(rep(letters[1:12], 4))
c2 <- paste(rep(letters[13:24], 4))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c1, c2), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#replacing 8 strings in each column
df[sample(nrow(df), 8),]$c1 <- ""
df[sample(nrow(df), 8),]$c2 <- ""
df
```

For this we know that two letters (for example, `i` and `u`) are paired. However some of the data values are missing, where one column is partially completed or empty. How would I fill in the values which are partially completed in this example?

(I know I'm supposed to show how I've tried to do this, but I'm stumped and couldn't find anything)

Comment: Will there be a case when they might both be empty?

Comment: No, but I'm curious as to how the answer would change if that was the case!

Comment: What would you do if you had no label title for "female." The data has two possibilities. How do you decide between "Mrs" and "Ms"?

Comment: As I wrote (but I guess I wasn't clear, sorry!), if the gender is female, then the title is "Ms". Even though the title can be "Ms" or "Mrs" and then the gender will be female.

Comment: Side note: I haven't posted that much on stack overflow, I'm really not sure why this would be down voted? Is it too simple or a replicate? I just want to make sure I don't make the same mistake again!

Comment: @user3389288 Unfortunately the down voter didn't seem to leave a comment to explain. But maybe the issue is your title involves a much more broad problem but you really just had this gender/title thing. Your title implies some type of general purpose imputation algorithm. You gave sample data which is nice. Sometimes people get upset when you don't show any code that you've tried. We like to think you make a good-faith effort to at least try to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the tips! I did have a hard time making a title for this, same with searching for similar questions. But next time I will make sure to put in code I've tried!

Comment: @user3389288 No problem. Don't let the down vote discourage you too much. We're tying to build a high quality Q&A site. So think about whether any other person in the world might have the same problem as you and what they might search for if they did. Hopefully the types of questions we answer on this site are broad enough to help many people. If it's unlikely to be useful for others, it's more likely to get down voted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
#Find those where there is no title
noTitle = which(df$title=="")
#And fill them in based on the gender
df$title[noTitle] = ifelse(grepl("[Ff]",df$gender[noTitle]), "Ms", "Mr")
#Do the same for gender
noGender = which(df$gender=="")
df$gender[noGender] = ifelse(grepl("[Ss]",df$title[noGender]), "female", "male")
```

If they were both empty then there would be a check to start with and a convert them as appropriate; something like:

```
#Find where both empty
Neither = intersect( which(df$title=""), which(df$gender=="") )
##Do something here
```